# excel - Using the value from one cell to reference value in a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the value in one cell to be used to reference another cell. 
So far what I've found is that the following formula should do the trick but somehow I can't get it to work.

In cell `E5` I have the sheet name which is build up as `XX-XX-XX-XX` in which the `XX`'s are all numerical values.

In another cell I want to have the data that's in cell `D2` from the sheet `12-12-12-12`.

I have tried the following formula but something doesn't seem to work:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&E5&"'!"&"D2")
```

If I check out the formula in error check it goes to this before it fails:

```
=INDIRECT("'12-12-12-12!D2")
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Okay found my error.. The name of the sheet was incorrect so it tried to reference a totally different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT("'"&E5&"'"&"!D2")
```

or if you want the cell reference separate from the !

```
=INDIRECT("'"&E5&"'"&"!"&"D2")
```